# Input box text is not showing text after using JQuery slidedown()

Tags: php, javascript, jquery

I have a form where if they have a agent they select the button multiple input boxes slide down using SlideDown() in JQuery.  Once text is added and submitted the values are stored as sessions and if something is incorrect then the user is sent back to form page and has to correct.  Now I have it where the input boxes will slide down if sent back with the values assigned to the appropriate boxes.  But the values do not show up, you cannot see them and if you click on one you see where the cursor is and you can tell the values are there.

Input section code:

```
<div class="agensele"> Do you have an agent? <input type="submit"  value="Yes"  name="agentsele" class="agentsele"/></div><!----- END .InputInner ---------->

<input type="hidden" value="" name="hiddenagentsele" />

     <div class="noagensele"> Do you have an agent? <input type="submit"  value="No" name="noagentsele" class="noagentsele"/> </div><!----- END .InputInner ---------->
     <input type="hidden" value="" name="hiddennoagentsele" />
</div><!---------------------------------END .InputContaienr ----------------------------------->
<script>
$(".agentsele").click(function () {
    return false;   
});
$(".agentsele").click(function () {
    $('input[name=hiddenagentsele]').val("clicked");
    $('input[name=hiddennoagentsele]').val("unclicked");    
});
$(".noagentsele").click(function () {
    return false;   
});
$(".noagentsele").click(function () {
    $('input[name=hiddennoagentsele]').val("clicked");  
    $('input[name=hiddenagentsele]').val("unclicked");
});

</script>
<br>
<div class="InputContainer">
<span class="agent">Agent Name: </span><div class="InputInner"> <input type="text" name="agentname"  class="agentinput" value="<?php echo $_SESSION['agentname']; ?>"></div><!----- END .InputInner ---------->
<?php 
$setError=$_GET['seterror']; 
if($setError == 1){
if (!isset($_SESSION['agentname']) && (isset($_SESSION['yesele']))){
    echo "<span style='color:red;' class='errorMsg'>*Required</span>";
    }
}
?>


</div><!---------------------------------END .InputContaienr ----------------------------------->

<div class="InputContainer">
<span class="agent">Agent Phone Number: </span><div class="InputInner"> <input type="text" name="agentphone"  class="agentinput" value="<?php echo $_SESSION['agentphone']; ?>"></div><!----- END .InputInner ---------->
<?php 
$setError=$_GET['seterror']; 
if($setError == 1){
if (!isset($_SESSION['agentphone']) && (isset($_SESSION['yesele']))){
    echo "<span style='color:red;' class='errorMsg'>*Required</span>";
    }
}
?>



</div><!---------------------------------END .InputContaienr ----------------------------------->
<div class="InputContainer">
<span class="agent">Agent's Email: </span><div class="InputInner"> <input type="text" name="agentemail"  class="agentinput" value="<?php echo $_SESSION['agentemail']; ?>" ></div><!----- END .InputInner ---------->
<?php 
$setError=$_GET['seterror']; 
if($setError == 1){
if (!isset($_SESSION['agentemail']) && (isset($_SESSION['yesele'])) ){
    echo "<span style='color:red;' class='errorMsg'>*Required</span>";
    }
}
?>


</div><!---------------------------------END .InputContaienr ----------------------------------->
<div class="InputContainer">
<span class="agent">Confirm Agent's Email: </span><div class="InputInner"> <input type="text" name="agentemailone"  class="agentinput" value="<?php echo $_SESSION['agentemail']; ?>" ></div><!----- END .InputInner ---------->
<?php 
             $setError=$_GET['seterror'];
             if ($setError == 2){

                echo "<div style='color:red;' class='errorMsg'> Your Agent Emails Did Not Match</div>";
             }

             ?>


</div><!---------------------------------END .InputContaienr ----------------------------------->
 <script type='text/javascript'>
    function analyzeagentsection() {

            $(".agentinput").slideDown(1000, function() {});
            $(".agent").slideDown(1000, function() {});

            $(".agentsele").css("visibility", "hidden");
            $(".agensele").css("visibility", "hidden");
            $(".noagentsele").css("visibility", "visible");
            $(".noagensele").css("visibility", "visible");
            $(".agentinput").css("visibility", "visible");

    }
    </script>
    <?php 

if ($_SESSION['yesele'] == 'yes'){

echo '<script type="text/javascript">'
   , 'analyzeagentsection();'
    ,'</script>';
}
    ?>
<script>
$(".agentsele").click(function () {

    //dropdown.bind('change', function(){   
    $(".agentinput").slideDown(1000,function(){
    });
    $(".agent").slideDown(1000,function(){
    });
    $(".agentsele").css("visibility", "hidden");
    $(".agensele").css("visibility", "hidden");
    $(".noagentsele").css("visibility", "visible");
    $(".noagensele").css("visibility", "visible");
    $(".agentinput").css("visibility", "visible");
});

$(".noagentsele").click(function () {

    //dropdown.bind('change', function(){   
    $(".agentinput").slideUp(1000,function(){
    });
    $(".agent").slideUp(1000,function(){
    });
    $(".agentsele").css("visibility", "visible");
    $(".agensele").css("visibility", "visible");
    $(".noagentsele").css("visibility", "hidden");
    $(".noagensele").css("visibility", "hidden");
    $(".agentinput").css("visibility", "hidden");
});

</script>
```

Css code:

```
    .agent {
    display: none;
    float: left;
    width: 100%;
    margin-bottom: 1%;


}
.agentinput {
    display:none; width:100%; float:left; /*height:auto;*/

}
.noagentsele {
    visibility:hidden;
}
.noagensele{
    visibility:hidden;
    display: block;
}
.agentsele {

}
.agensele{

    display: block;
}
```

Comment: when page is loaded your class agentinput is displayed none initially and is displayed block after analyzeagentsection() function is called. right?

Comment: do you get value in the input box if agentinput class is displayed block initially? issue is, it is not displayed when initially displayed none. right?

Comment: I actually fixed it thatnk you!

Answer (score 0):

I actually just made a value JavaScript checked and if so would just change the boxes to visible.

Code:

```
 <script type='text/javascript'>
    function analyzeagentsection() {

            $(".agentinput").slideDown(1000, function() {});
            $(".agent").slideDown(1000, function() {});

            $(".agentsele").css("visibility", "hidden");
            $(".agensele").css("visibility", "hidden");
            $(".noagentsele").css("visibility", "visible");
            $(".noagensele").css("visibility", "visible");
            $(".agentinput").css("visibility", "visible");



    }
    </script>
    <?php 

if ($_SESSION['yesele'] == 'yes'){

echo '<script type="text/javascript">'
   , 'analyzeagentsection();'
    ,'</script>';
}
    ?>
<script>
```

thanks for your hard work!